# Anyone knows how to do NIFI lookup for multiple columns?

Tags: apache-nifi

I try this:

1. lookuprecord, but there are not options for me to lookup multiple columns at the same time, only can perform one by one.
2. queryrecord to do inner join, but I have not idea how to join two flowfiles.

Anyone has ideas how to lookup for multiple columns?

Comment: Can you share an example of what you're trying to do? Those two things are not really the same. Are you working with one FlowFile and want to add fields from somewhere else like a database? Or are you trying to join two FlowFiles based on the values in the fields?